# what is select=not(mod(n\,500)) doing in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to get a picture collage(getting images from various timeframes and combining into one image) with FFmpeg I copied this code from the internet

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10 -i uploads/high.webm -frames 1 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,500)),scale=480:360,tile=10x5" out.webp
```

it is working but I couldn't figout how it is working more specifically what is this `select=not(mod(n\,500))`

Comment: Select every 500th frame. `select` selects frames, `n` is the number of the frame (starting from 0), `mod` is modulo, `not` negates the modulo since a zero result means discard the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `select=not(mod(n\,500))`,

`select` invokes the [select](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) video filter, which sends forward a frame if expression evaluates to non-zero, else discards it.

`mod(var,X)` returns the modulus (remainder after division)
 of dividing `var` by `X`. In `mod(n,500)`, `n` is the current frame's index, starting from zero, so this expression will evaluate to 0, 1, 2 ... 498, 499, 0, 1, 2, ... 498, 499, 0, 1, 2... for increasing `n`.

`not(expr)` inverts the value of the expression contained inside the brackets - 0 if expr is non-zero and 1 if expr evaluates to zero.

Comment: does this have something to do with the frame rate? 

`ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -b 100K -r 10 -vf "select(not(mod(n/5))" out.mp4`

What happens in this case? still my frame rate is 10?

Comment: The framerate is converted to `10` but after `select` has been applied.